# I am trying to store key values of a 5GB XML file into Cassandra keyspace

Tags: java, cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli, pycassa

I am fairly new to Java and Cassandra, I am trying to write(store Key Values) of a 5GB XML file into Cassandra. The file is on the same cluster as Cassandra. I am not sure if the sstableloader is needed and the only way to complete this task or may there  be a simpler option? If the sstableloader is the only way, how do I use a xml file with sstableloader, all the documentation Ive found on using sstableloader states the data must be in CSV format.  Thanks in advance.